# MKMapView compare overlay rectangle with map rectangle

Tags: ios, overlay, mapkit, polygon

I have a MKMapView in my app with some overlays, which are shown correctly. 
These overlays draw images inside the

```
- (void) drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context
```

The MapView allows zooming and i want to avoid drawing the images at a specific zoom level

Is there a way to determine inside this method whether the overlay rectangle is greater than the mapview rectangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your overlay is made from `myOverlay` `(MyOverlay *)` and `myOverlayView` `(MyOverlayView *)`

Inside `- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context` you can get reference to `myOverlay` like this:

```
MyOverlay *myOverlay = (MyOverlay *)self.overlay;
```

It should be easy to compare `myOverlay.boundingRect` and `mapRect` from here on.